# MySQL query to select records for the past N days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table with a `date_added` column in the format of `2014-09-30 20:39:17` and I have a web page with filter options for users.  Basically I want to use variables to select different date ranges like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_added = /* EVERYTHING POSTED TODAY */
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_added = /* EVERYTHING POSTED WITHIN LAST 7 DAYS */
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_added = /* EVERYTHING POSTED WITHIN LAST 30 DAYS */
```

What would I need to put in to get those variables to work?

Comment: The manual would be a good place to start: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and very simple `INTERVAL` arithmetic.

In the following examples assume that query was executed at `2014-10-21 22:25:28`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_added >= CURRENT_DATE
                                  -- >= 2014-10-21 00:00:00

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_added >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
                                  -- >= 2014-10-20 22:25:28

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_added >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
                                  -- >= 2014-10-14 00:00:00

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_added >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
                                  -- >= 2014-09-21 00:00:00
```